# Unable to send a string in my http post using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, string, http, post

I'm new to AngularJS and I am having trouble with sending a string in my http post.  I am currently using this format to send http posts which is from an example that I got online,

```
        $http({

            method: 'POST',

            url: 'http://example.com/',

            data: { 'ver':$scope.version, 

            'deviceTime':moment().valueOf(), 

            'name':$scope.$storage.name, 

            'email':$scope.$storage.email, 

            'phone':$scope.$storage.phone, 

            'device':$scope.$storage.device, 

            'endTime': $scope.$storage.end },

            headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

        })

    };
```

although this sends as an object.  When I try to send the information as such, in string format:

```
        $http({

            method: 'POST',

            url: 'http://example.com/',

            data:'ver=' + $scope.version,

            headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

        })
    };
```

the post does not appear in the server.  Any assistance on how I would go about sending a string alone would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in post method:

```
  $http.post("some url",{'param1':paramvalue,'param2':param2value})
```

Your paramvalue should be able to be a string with no problems.  Note that if your string is "name=value" then you end up with something like "param1=name=value" and the "name=value" will get encoded in your URL.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I tried this method and I did not receive it on the server end.